# MariaDB of XAMPP hanging when trying to add fulltext search for a large table's column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, mariadb

I have `XAMPP 5.6.15` for Windows which is running `10.1.9-MariaDB`. I have a table, InnoDB, with large amount of records and size, 49888 records and 245 MiB size. The main of its size in a column contains text named tafText.

Using PHPMyAdmin, I try to set fulltext search on that column. However, mysqld is hanged and the database server is topped:

[image]

The following is a copy of the error log generated after the occurrence of the error:

```
    2016-10-18 20:49:22 13360 [Note] InnoDB: Online DDL : Start
2016-10-18 20:49:22 13360 [Note] InnoDB: Online DDL : Start reading clustered index of the table and create temporary files
2016-10-18 20:49:22 1d78  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 7544 in file row0merge.cc line 892
InnoDB: Failing assertion: b < &block[srv_sort_buf_size]
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
161018 20:49:22 [ERROR] mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see http://kb.askmonty.org/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.1.9-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=2
max_threads=1001
thread_count=2
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 787099 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
mysqld.exe!my_parameter_handler()
mysqld.exe!my_mb_ctype_mb()
mysqld.exe!?set_charset@String@@QAEXPBUcharset_info_st@@@Z()
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
ntdll.dll!RtlSubscribeWnfStateChangeNotification()
ntdll.dll!RtlSubscribeWnfStateChangeNotification()
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

What is the wrong in mysql settings that I have which makes this operation failed?

The following is copy of InnoDB related settings in my.ini:

```
# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir = "C:/xampp-3/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "C:/xampp-3/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "C:/xampp-3/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 125M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to find with google, if you type the "InnoDB: Failing assertion: b < &block[srv_sort_buf_size]" :)

This bug was reported in https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9129 , fixed in MariaDB 10.1.10. You have 10.1.9, so there it is not fixed.

Comment: So, I have to upgrade my MariaDB?

Comment: I guess so, if you want to get rid of that bug

Comment: Well, I have installed MariaDB 10.1.18 and everything goes fine now!